# Change field form field label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a code that generates a form for me:

```
<%= form_for(@member) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to customize the label for this field, ie. set a non-default one.

How would I do that?

Comment: umm meaby replace f.label :email with f.label "whatever"?

Comment: Hah, I feel so dumb.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad it worked. I have also added it as a comment so you can approve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could be tempted to replace `f.label :email` with `f.label "whatever"`, but this'll put you in troubles: you won't be able to use your label for quick access to your text field by clicking on the label's area. Make it this way:

```
<%= f.label :email, "Something" %>
```

You text field and label will be associated, but the last one just will be having a different representation a page.

Comment: How to change all f.label, adding (for example) at the end a ":"? ... hou to overwrite label method?

Answer (score 0):

umm maybe replace `f.label :email` with `f.label :email, "whatever"`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm sorry what are you talking about? if you read the comments below his post you will see that this helped the OP.

Comment: You'll change the label's `for` attribute this way, which'll break the connection between the label and its corresponding text field.